# How IP resolves a hostname?

Tags: networking, ip

I understand that the job of IP in the TCP stack, when dealing with an outgoing message, is to resolve an IP address from a host name and add this address as a header.

Is this process that IP goes through equivalent to using a tool like nslookup for a given hostname?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. IP doesn't know anything about device names, it only deals with IP addresses.

An application can query a DNS server or a hosts file to resolve a name into an IP address.  This must be done prior to using IP to forward a packet since IP can only use an IP address. Tools, like you mention, and other applications, such as browsers, query a DNS server (requires you have the IP address of a DNS server configured) or use a hosts file to resolve the name to an IP address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ron, just to clarify are you saying that the Application (e.g. a Browser) is responsible for resolving the IP address (by querying a DNS server), and that this happens before the Browser talks to the HTTP protocol in the Application layer of the TCP/IP stack?

Comment: HTTP is another application protocol and not part of the TCP/IP stack. HTTP, DNS, DHCP, etc. are all application protocols which are not part of the TCP/IP stack. TCP, UDP, etc. are in the Transport layer (layer 4 of the OSI model), and IP is the Network layer (layer-3 of the OSI model), so the TCP/IP stack encompasses layers 3 and 4 of the OSI model. The application layers are Session (layer 5), Presentation (layer 6) and Application (layer7) of the OSI model.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation Ron. It was my understanding that the "TCP/IP stack" was generally taken to refer to a stack of four layers, one of which was the Application layer (mapping to layers 5,6,7 of OSI model). But getting back to my original question, I'm still not clear at what stage the IP address is resolved when a program (browser) makes a request to send a message? Thanks

Comment: In your model, it would be in the application layer (OSI layers 5 to 7), where the application (browser, HTTP, etc.) is. The resolution must be complete before the request gets to TCP in layer-4 because TCP needs to establish an end-to-end connection to the server, and it uses IP at layer-3 to send and receive the message to the IP address of the server.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Ron, really appreciate it.